# How does scary transcluding caching work on MediaWiki?

Tags: caching, mediawiki, transclusion

We are running a small wiki farm (same topic; six languages and growing) and have recently updated most templates to use several layers of meta-templates in order to facilitate maintenance and readability.

We wish to standardise those templates for all languages, therefore most of them are going to contain the exact same code on each wiki. This is why, in order to further simplify maintenance, we are considering the use of scary transcluding (more specifically, substitution) so that those meta-templates are only stored on one wiki and only have to be updated on that wiki, not on every single version.

(Note: if you can think of a better idea, don't hesitate to comment on this post!)

However, scary transcluding is called so for being scarily inefficient, therefore I need to know more about the way content included that way is cached by MediaWiki.

If I understand correctly, the HTML output of a page is stored in the parser cache for a duration of $wgParserCacheExpireTime. The default is 1 day, but it's safe to increase it on a small to medium wiki because the content will get updated anyway if the page itself or an included page is updated (and in some other minor cases).

There's also a cache duration for scary transcluding: $wgTranscludeCacheExpiry. Good, because you wouldn't want to make that HTTP call every time. However, the default value of 1 hour is not suitable for smaller wikis, on which an article may only be viewed every now and then, therefore rendering that cache absolutely useless.

- If a page A uses a template B that includes template C from another wiki, does page A have to be entirely regenerated after $wgTranscludeCacheExpiry has been exceeded? Or can it still make use of the parser cache of template B until $wgParserCacheExpireTime has been exceeded?
- You could then increase $wgTranscludeCacheExpiry to a month, just like the parser cache, but a page wouldn't get updated automatically if the transcluded template was, would it?
- If yes, would refreshing the pages using that transcluded template be the only solution to update the other wikis?

Answer (score 1):

IMHO the solution to find out is simple: try it! [$wgScaryTranscluding](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgScaryTranscluding) is rarely used, but the few who tried enabling it reported having very few problems. There are also JavaScript-based alternatives, see the manual.

Purging is rarely a big issue: a crosswiki template is unlikely to contain stuff you absolutely want to get out right now. If the cache doesn't feel aggressive enough for you, set it to a week or month and see if something goes wrong. [Ilmari Karonen suggests](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/User:Ilmari_Karonen/Performance_tuning) such a long cache even for HTML after all.